# PHP not recognizing GET variables with hash in the URL

Tags: php

I have a URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/page.php#tabname
```

The hash will automatically open a specific tab on the page.

I need to work with a _GET variable, and the URL is like:

```
http://www.example.com/page.php#tabname?color=red
```

Then on the page, I have:

```
echo $_GET['red'];
```

...but I am getting an undefined index error. How do I get PHP to recognize the variable?

Comment: The # part of a url typically stays on the client - the browser doesn't send any of it to the server.  You _could_ have some javascript that queries it and sends it...

Comment: It should also be `echo $_GET['color']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the query string before the hash:

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?color=red#tabname
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything after the hash is not sent to the server. Regardless, you should probably format your url so you send the GET parameters correctly.

http://www.example.com/page.php#tabname?color=red

should be

http://www.example.com/page.php?color=red#tabname